# C: Starting and naming a string array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to commence a string array from a user prompt and to name the array. I keep getting errors regardless of how I write this. I am unsure if I need to add a fictitious number to the [] or not.

```
    do
    {
        printf("What is your name?\n"); 
        char str[] = get_string(); 'error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal'
    }
    while (namelen[i] = int); //error: use of undeclared identifier 'namelen'    
char str[49] = namelen;  //error: use of undeclared identifier'namelen'
```

Comment: your code snippet is wrong _and_ not in sync with the error message... post the actual error message corresponding to the source code you posted.

Comment: If you declare `namelen[]` in the scope of the do...while then the array is only a valid reference inside that scope.

Comment: `char str namelen[]` is not valid C code and neither is `namelen[i] = int`

Comment: You need declare `namelen` outside loop. E.g `char x, y, *namelen;`...`namelen = get_string();`...`char str[50]; strncpy(str, namelen, 50);str[49]=0;`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the way you thought to make this code. I guess your variables `x` and `y` don't have any purpose for the sake of this specific problem. But what do you intend with that do/while loop? What do you mean by `namelen[i] = int`? Notice that `i` is not declared anywhere. What is `namelen` supposed to be? What does `get_string()` returns?

Comment: What is your question?  The goal is unclear "commence a string array from a user prompt and to name the array".

Comment: The exercise is that the user is prompted to enter their name. I need this to become an array so that I can iterate through it later in the program. The do-while was intended to keep prompting the user if they enter a number. Namelen is just a name I wanted to give the array. Because I don't know what the user will enter, I don't know the length of the array prior to iterating through it.

Comment: I gather kids here think 'reputation' here means something so they all jump in to hit the down arrow if you ask a question so you can learn. LOL.

Comment: Milack - get_string() returns a string, apparently. I think it might be part of the Harvard CS library. The line above it is the user prompt. The code is a snippet.  'Namelen' is not c code. It's a name I want to call the array.  The section I posted is the do-while loop to receive a response from the user which is to become the array.

Comment: Is this the `get_string()` function you're using? https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string

Answer (score 0):

Think of the loop as being separate from the function. You're declaring `namelen` over and over and over but only inside the loop. It won't be usable outside of the loop. Your condition `namelen[i] = int` is also not a real condition. Are you trying to get the loop to continue to run while `namelen[i]` is an integer? That doesn't make any sense since an `int` is different from a `char`.

I think you need to clarify your question and your code. It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do here.

If I had to guess, you want code more aligned with the following:

```
int main(void)
{
    char namelen[49];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    gets(namelen);

    printf(namelen);
}
```

Comment: `gets()` has been depreciate in C99 and since C11 is no longer part of the C standard library.  Suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some code like this:

```
#define NAME_MAXLEN 50

int main(void)
{
    char name[NAME_MAXLEN];

    do
    {
        printf("What is your name?\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
    }
    while (!validate_name(name));

    // Do whatever you need with the name array.
}

int validate_name(const char *name)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        char c = name[i];

        if (!(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') &&
            !(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') &&
            c != ' ')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The function `scanf` will get the input from the user and store it at the `name` array. After that, the input will be validated by the `validate_name()` function. If the name isn't valid, the loop will execute again until a valid name is given.

The `validate_name()` function will sweep the characters of the `name` string one by one, searching for a character that is not a letter or a blank space. If it finds one, the string is considered invalid, and zero is returned. If none is found, 1 is returned, which means the given name is ok.

### EDIT

This code only works if the user types a name shorter than 50 characters, because that's the number of characters I statically allocated to my string. If you need more characters, you can increase that number, which is simple and effective. You can also use dynamic allocation of memory, so that you can allocate an initial memory that's big enough to fit the user entry and later free the excess, but that solution is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll closely look at this.

Comment: The purpose of getting the name from the user is to extract the initials, capitalise them, then print them to the terminal.